# Let S find basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let the subspace $S =\bigl\langle(1,1,2,2,-1,-1),(3,2,1,1,2,3),(4,3,2,1,1,2)\bigr\rangle$, find a basis of S
$\left\{v \in \mathbb{R}: \forall u \in S, \langle u\mid v\rangle=0\right\}$

I know that

Let $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A set $\{v_1, v_2, . . . , v_k \} $of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a basis for $S$ if the following conditions are satisfied:

1. Span $\left\{v_1, v_2, . . . , v_k\right\} = S$
2. The vectors $v_1, v_2, . . . , v_k$ are linearly independent

How I must proceed, I think that I should make a homogeneous matrix with the 3 vectors of S, and see with gaussian elimination if vectors are independent, but I'm not nothing sure

Comment: Have you ever heard of the "*Gram-Schmidt Process*"?

Comment: i just search Gram-Schmidt Process, you know what is the proof of the process?, i need explain that, thanks bro ! :))

Comment: You can prove it yourself.  Also, a proof should be included in any textbook where Gram-schmidt is mentioned (*including likely your own textbook you are using*) unless of course it is included in the exercises there.